# Default filter in the form "Available stock"

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, stock

Using the form `InventOnHandItem`to get information about available stock, in a multi-company configuration, we have remarked that the default filter (query), is not the same in the different companies.

In some companies, the form filters on the value of `InventSum.Closed` or on the value of `InventSum.ClosedQty`. In some others all data are displayed.

We have searched for parameters defining this behaviour, but we have found none. It must be programmatical : by which way can we define the default value of this filter ?

Comment: From what I remember, I think this is user-specific and it just saves your last settings? Do you have any sample code you're looking at? This isn't exactly a programming question.

Comment: Thank you Alex. This is not user specific: user settings are overrided. I had a look at codes like `\Classes\InventDimCtrl_Frm_OnHand.modifyQuery()` but I didn't catch the thing yet.